# Not able to use componentsSeparatedByString on a string stored inNSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsmutablearray, xml-parsing

I'm parsing an xml which contains string that needs to be displayed on the screen. Here is the code doing that.

```
[gTutorialTextList addObject:[attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"]];
```

Here *value* is the attribute which contains the text in xml and *gTutorialTextList* is my NSMutableArray.

What I need is I need to break up the line when ever *\n* comes in the string. Here is the code that performs that.

```
[[gTutorialTextList objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
```

But right now I'm not able to do that. I'm not getting the array of strings separated by *\n*. When I put the NSString directly, it is working fine.

Please Help. I think I conveyed my doubt properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you log the value of the object at index 0 like:

```
NSString *logString   = [gTutorialTextList objectAtIndex:0]
NSLog(@"-->%@<--", logString);
NSArray *stringArray = [logString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSLog(@"%@", stringArray);
```

This should give you a clear picture of what is going on.

Comment: Here are the outputs.      -->\nSample Text\nSample Text\nSample Text<--. And the output of text array is (
    "\\nSample Text\\nSample Text\\nSample Text"
)

Comment: @Aaron Looks like you have a real backslash in the input string. Try with `[[gTutorialTextList objectAtIndex:0] componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\n"];`

Comment: @Jilouc Thankz buddy...I was able to figure it out. Previously when I was using NSString directly, that was not an issue. Hence I made the mistake on the parsed string.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the issue by putting *\\n* as argument in the componentSeparatedByString.

I think when we are reading from xml, the \n is interpreted as newline character...

Thankz..